# Why Fragment onResume() not udating RecyclerView Correctly?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

in my app i schedule downloading task using AlarmManager when Download time arrives from Alarm Receiver Service i Download File and Delete from ArrayList of Custom Object and then save it using sharedpref and after this starting Activity if it is already running like this

```
if (mIsInForegroundMode == true) {
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, DownloadingActivity.class);
                            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent1);

                        }
```

if activity running then `Fragment` onResume() will be called where i am getting saved list and updating

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getDestroyedData();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}  

public void getDestroyedData() {
    String getPendingDownloadsList = preferences.getString("plist", "");

    Type type2 = new TypeToken<List<DownloadingActivity.scheduleListType>>(){}.getType();

    if (!getPendingDownloadsList.equals("")) {
        pending=gson.fromJson(getPendingDownloadsList, type2);


    }
}
```

Now when `onResume` of fragment runs  i successfully got list data but when `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is called data is updated on RecyclerView but it is not showing correct values but when i restart activity then `RecyclerView` shows correct values. i think `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` not working correctly.

AND ALSO THIS IS MY CODE FOR SETING ADAPTER IN onCreate()

```
adapter = new PendingAdapter(pending, this.getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this.getActivity()));
```

**UPDATE**
this is my Adapter

```
public class PendingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PendingAdapter.PendingHolder> {

    ArrayList<DownloadingActivity.scheduleListType> pendingList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    PendingAdapter(ArrayList<DownloadingActivity.scheduleListType> pendingList, Context c) {

        this.pendingList = pendingList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public PendingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pending, parent, false);
        PendingHolder pendingHolder = new PendingHolder(v);
        return pendingHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PendingHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.fileName.setText(pendingList.get(position).name);
        if (pendingList.get(position).reqCODE != 0) {
            holder.pendingType.setText("Start At " + pendingList.get(position).hour + ":" + pendingList.get(position).minute);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pendingList.size();
    }


     //also tried this function
   /** public void swap(ArrayList<DownloadingActivity.scheduleListType> newList) {
        if (pendingList != null) {
            pendingList.clear();
            pendingList.addAll(newList);
        } else {
            pendingList = newList;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }**/

    public class PendingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView fileName, pendingType;
        Button downloadByMobileBtn, removeFromPending;

        public PendingHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            pendingType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pendingType);

            fileName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pendingFileNameTXT);
            downloadByMobileBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.downloadByMobileBTN);
            removeFromPending = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.removeFromPending);

            downloadByMobileBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            removeFromPending.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        ShowRemoveDialog(position);
                    }
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int p = getAdapterPosition();

            if(p!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                if (v.getId() == downloadByMobileBtn.getId()) {


                    ShowDialog(p);
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the list reference you pass to the adapter gets updated.
Creating a new list every time was the problem in my case.
Eg.

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(myList);
myList = GetaNewList(); // Cause of error
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Instead I passed a reference to my list and updated the existing list.

```
GetUpdatedList(myList);
```

Inside the function -

```
GetUpdatedList(ArrayList<String> myList)
{
  myList.Append("foo");
}
```

Comment: i have already tried that by `pending.clear()` and then `pending.addAll(tempPending)` but nothing works what i can do here pls help

Answer (score 0):

seems `pending` is a list. then you should not reassign this list coz You got here new pointer and adapter will still point to old one. you should clear list and then add items to it.
Something like this:

```
pending.clear();
pending.addAll(gson.fromJson(getPendingDownloadsList, type2));
```

Comment: also RecyclerView updated correctly when deleting row by `removeFromPending` button @Stepan

Comment: change again updating list to above code this is correct way. and no need to  write like `ArrayList` -  write everywhere `List` in types only on creation you can write `new ArrayList`

Comment: what is differebce between `List` and `ArrayList`

Comment: nothing is solving my problem please provide any help